# Indexing a dictionary by passing a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib, color-scheme

I'm trying to plot a data frame using colors stored in a dictionary.
This code works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), index=range(100), columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df + [-2, 0, 2, 4]
x = list(range(100, 1100, 10))
clrhex = {'abcd':'#FFA500', 'efgh':'#FF0000','ijkl':'#000000','mnop':'#6495ED'}

plt.plot(x, df, color=[clrhex['abcd'], clrhex['efgh'], clrhex['ijkl'], clrhex['mnop']])
plt.show()
```

but I'd like to make this shorter by indexing the dictionary with a list. This:

```
plt.plot(x, df, color=clrhex['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop'])
```

gives the following error message:

```
Invalid RGBA argument
```

How can I get multiple values from a dictionary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using matplotlib > 1.5, using `set_color_cycle` will bring up a depreciation message:

> c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py:106:
>  
>   MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The set_color_cycle attribute was
>   deprecated in version 1.5. Use set_prop_cycle instead.

So, using `set_prop_cycle` you can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), index=range(100), columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df + [-2, 0, 2, 4]
x = list(range(100, 1100, 10))
clrhex = {'abcd':'#FFA500', 'efgh':'#FF0000','ijkl':'#000000','mnop':'#6495ED'}

plt.gca().set_prop_cycle('color', [clrhex[i] for i in ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop']])
plt.plot(x, df)

plt.show()
```

The advantage of using `set_prop_cycle` is that you can use it with other things not just color, i.e. linestyles, or linewidths. Below is some modified code that shows how to change both the color and the linewidths (if you ever wanted to), and uses the object oriented API:

```
from cycler import cycler

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), index=range(100), columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df + [-2, 0, 2, 4]
x = list(range(100, 1100, 10))
clrhex = {'abcd':'#FFA500', 'efgh':'#FF0000','ijkl':'#000000','mnop':'#6495ED'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler('color', [clrhex[i] for i in ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop']]) + 
    cycler('lw', [1,2,3,4]))

ax.plot(x, df)

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks !
However, although I'm not getting any error messages the colors appearing now are clearly not the ones defined in the dictionary but some random ones...

Comment: @DusanKojic Ah, you are right, you need to call `set_prop_cycle` before you plot anything. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do it with comprehension in fewer characters:

```
color=[clrhex[i] for i in ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop']]
```

**EDIT**

Your code didn't work for me so I used this:

```
plt.plot(x, df)
plt.gca().set_color_cycle([clrhex[i] for i in ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop']])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Looks exactly like the kind of advice I was looking for, however the error message persists...